# Problems while dynamically allocating memory for a read input function

Tags: c, user-input, dynamic-memory-allocation, getchar

I am having trouble with a function that should read a string from the user. I am always getting `(null)` as the output.

Is this even a "right" approach for that kind of problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getString(char *input);

int main(void)
{
        char *arr = NULL;
        printf("please enter string: ");
        getString(arr);
        printf("%s", arr);
        return 0;
}

int getString(char *input)
{
        int i;
        char c;
        char *tmp;
        input = malloc(sizeof(char));
        for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
                tmp = realloc(input, (i + 2) * sizeof(char));
                if (tmp == NULL) {
                        free(input);
                        printf("allocation error");
                        return -1;
                }
                input = tmp;
                input[i] = c;
        }
        input[i] = '\0';
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically allocate the string you need to pass a *pointer to `char*`*, not just a `char *`. This way, the function can modify the real `char *` pointer and the caller will see the result. In your current code, the `input` variable only exists inside the function and does not affect the variable used by the caller, therefore your `arr` stays unchanged (`NULL`).

Something like this:

```
int getString(char **input)
{
        int i;
        char c;
        char *tmp, *cur = NULL;

        // No initial malloc() needed here.
        // Let realloc() do the job passing NULL the first time.

        for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
                tmp = realloc(cur, (i + 2) * sizeof(char));
                if (tmp == NULL) {
                        free(cur);
                        printf("allocation error");
                        return -1;
                }
                cur = tmp;
                cur[i] = c;
        }

        cur[i] = '\0';
        *input = cur;
        return 0;
}
```

And then pass the parameter like this:

```
getString(&arr);
```

Comment: Don't I have to put an `free(cur);` before the `return 0;` to prevent a memory leak?

Comment: @sneeed absolutely not, you give the memory to the caller (`*input = cur`). If you free before returning everything becomes invalid.After the function return it's the caller's job to use the data and free it when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `input` pointer, since it is local to your function and get deallocated when the program leaves from the function, so in `main` the `arr` is still `NULL`.

```
int* getString(char *input);

int main(void)
{
        //...
        arr = getString(arr);
        //...
}

int* getString(char *input)
{
        //...
        return input;
}
```

Comment: Tanks for your explanation!